# Python, Issue with Regex. Trying to scrape for some comicbook titles

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to scrape for comic book titles and their respective numbers, [from this site.](http://www.comiclistdatabase.com/doku.php?id=comiclist_for_09_10_2014)

But I'm having issue with Regex which I've never used before.
I don't want to bore you with my full code, suffice it say I'm using beautiful soup, and what I need from Regex is simply to point to the title name and also the episode number of each comic title, out of the list looping through.

As you can tell from the webpage this should be simplicity itself, the Publisher name comes in all caps, always followed by the title, always followed by a #-symbol, always followed by the episode number.

Here is my approach:

```
import re

text = "876876 PUBLISHER   title #345 jklhljhljh"

texpat = re.compile(r"PUBLISHER(.*?)#")
thename = pattern.search(text)
name = thename.group()

numpat = re.compile(r"#(\d+)")
num = numpat.search(text)

print(name)
print(num.group())
```

The output is:

```
PUBLISHER   title #
#345
```

But it should be:

```
title
345
```

I can use the replace string method to remove the stuff I don't want, but then I get stuck with this output:

```
   title
```

and name.strip() or name.lstrip() does NOT remove the extra three spaces.
It's late, I've never used regex before, I'm sure I'm doing something stupid.

Comment: The funny thing is that the entries from that site are in a table; using Cmd+Drag or Ctrl+Drag you can select just one column of that table.

Answer (score 2):

I would utilize [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) here to help with html parsing:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.comiclistdatabase.com/doku.php?id=comiclist_for_09_10_2014"

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

for row in soup.select('div.table tr')[1:]:
    publisher = row.find('td', class_='col1').text
    title = row.find('td', class_='col2').text
    print {'publisher': publisher, 'title': title}
```

Prints:

```
{'publisher': u'AMIGO COMICS', 'title': u'Ghost Wolf #4 (Of 4)$3.99 '}
{'publisher': u'AMIGO COMICS', 'title': u'Rogues Volume 2 Cold Ship #4 (Of 5)'}
{'publisher': u'ARCHIE COMIC PUBLICATIONS', 'title': u'Archie Giant Comics Digest TP'}
{'publisher': u'ARCHIE COMIC PUBLICATIONS', 'title': u'Betty And Veronica #272 (Dan Parent Regular Cover)'}
...
```

---

Then, you can grab the number from the title if you want to extract it too. I'm using `#(\d+)` regular expression that matches a hashtag followed by 1 or more digits, parenthesis help to [capture](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) the number:

```
import re
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.comiclistdatabase.com/doku.php?id=comiclist_for_09_10_2014"

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

NUMBER_RE = re.compile('#(\d+)')
for row in soup.select('div.table tr')[1:]:
    publisher = row.find('td', class_='col1').text
    title = row.find('td', class_='col2').text
    match = NUMBER_RE.search(title)
    number = match.group(1) if match else 'n/a'

    print {'publisher': publisher, 'title': title, 'number': number}
```

Prints:

```
{'publisher': u'AMIGO COMICS', 'number': u'4', 'title': u'Ghost Wolf #4 (Of 4)$3.99 '}
{'publisher': u'AMIGO COMICS', 'number': u'4', 'title': u'Rogues Volume 2 Cold Ship #4 (Of 5)'}
{'publisher': u'ARCHIE COMIC PUBLICATIONS', 'number': 'n/a', 'title': u'Archie Giant Comics Digest TP'}
...
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. I think OP wants just the title column so you could leave out publisher

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

text = "876876 PUBLISHER   title #345 jklhljhljh"

texpat = re.compile(r"PUBLISHER\s*(\S.*?)#")
thename = texpat.search(text)
name = thename.groups()[0]

numpat = re.compile(r"#(\d+)")
num = numpat.search(text)

print(name)
print(num.groups()[0])
```

The output is:

```
title 
345
```

Answer (score 1):

Match this to capture the title (in group one) and the number (in group two) with one expression:

```
PUBLISHER\s*(.+?)\s*#(\d+)
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/aP6rN2/1)

---

Then you need to use the array [`pattern.search(text).group(i)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) to get the capture group instead of the entire match:

```
import re

text = "876876 PUBLISHER   title #345 jklhljhljh"
pattern = re.compile(r"PUBLISHER\s*(.+?)\s*#(\d+)")

results = pattern.search(text)

print(results.group(1))
print(results.group(2))
```

Output:

```
title
345
```